# Mathematical explanation of the extinction paradox

Tags: mathematical-physics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I am trying to learn properly about scattering. For this I was pointed to Wave Propagation and Scattering in Random Media by Ishimaru.

I got a bit stuck in section 2-2 General properties of the Cross section.
In general I don't understand the extinction paradox and even if I've watched some youtube videos and read other references I still find this obscure.

I'll quote the bits I don't get but a full mathematical explanation would be appreciated.

> If the size of a particle is much greater than a wavelength the total cross section $\sigma_t$ approaches twice the geometric cross section $\sigma_g$.

Further down in the same page we have

> The total flux $S_i \sigma_g$ within the geometric cross section $\sigma_g$ is either scattered out or absorbed by the particle. Behind the particle there should be a shadow region where practically no wave exists.

Question: What is this shadow region? and why we have "practically no wave exists"

> In this shadow region the scattered wave from the particle is exactly equal to incident wave but 180 degrees out of phase abd this scattered flux is equal to $S_i \sigma_g$ in magnitude. The total scattered and absorbed flux, therefore, approaches $S_i \sigma_g + S_i \sigma_g$ and the total cross section $\sigma_t$ approaches
> $$
> \sigma_t \to 2S_i\frac{\sigma_g}{S_i} = 2\sigma_g
> $$

I get a bit confused because I don't understand the formulation, mathematical, of this phenomenon. Everything is stated but I cannot put this together using mathematical formulation.

There's also a reference (Van de Hulst - 1957) where the explanation is very similar to the one in this book with very little mathematical insight.

Can anyone clarify?

**Note**: The main reference is [Scattering and Propagation in Random media - Ishimaru](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Wave_Propagation_and_Scattering_in_Rando/gb44BQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=scattering%20theory%20of%20waves%20and%20particles%20in%20random%20media&printsec=frontcover)

**Update** : I think maybe this is consequence of the fact that at any point in space (where we have a scattering object) the electromagneting field can be written as:

$$
E(x) = E_{incident}(x) + E_{scattered}(x)
$$

If the wave is assumed to planar and assuming that *shadow area* means that for any $x$ in this area we have $E(x) = 0$ then we have

$$
E_{incident}(x) + E_{scattered}(x) = 0 \Rightarrow E_{incident}(x) = -E_{scattered}(x)
$$

This idea is taken from [Comment on The Extinction Paradox](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19840007890/downloads/19840007890.pdf).

**Note**: To be precise I should actually be talking about electromagnetic field I believe.

Please can anyone confirm my understanding is correct?